# System restore for kali linux?

Tags: linux

I made a mistake when I tried to delete Fern cracker, now I cant even find it anymore.

Installing it doesnt work. I have tried this under me, didnt work. got the error `E: Unable to locate package kali-linux-full`

How do I make a System restore or reinstalling the kali linux?

When I press on the setup I keep getting the error `Cannot find win32-loader.ini` but I can see the file in the folder where I run the setup from. so the file is there.

Is there anything I can try to reinstall the whole kali linux or doing a system restore?

I have fully installed kali linux on a laptop.

Type in the followings in your terminal:

Remove and purge Kali-Menu

```
apt-get remove --purge kali-menu && apt-get clean
```

Remove local applications in your profile

```
rm -rf .local/share/applications
```

Remove Kali Menus from .config

```
rm -rf .config/menus
```

Reboot your machine

```
reboot
```

Reinstall Kali-Menu

```
apt-get install kali-menu -y
```

If this doesn’t solve the menu problem, only then move to next step.

Reinstall Kali-linux-full

```
apt-get install kali-linux-full -y
```

Now your broken menu in Kali Linux should be back in order.