# apt connection is broken

Tags: linux, ip, kali-linux, apt

After I re-installed Kali-Linux, I got stuck without a connection in terminal. Unable to use `apt` and even `git clone`. I followed [a tutorial](https://superuser.com/questions/832648/system-restore-for-kali-linux) that left me broken because I cannot use apt to re-install kali-menu and kali-linux-full.

```
apt-get install kali-menu -y
```

With errors like this:

```
    Err:1 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 kali-menu all 2017.2.2
  Connection failed [IP: 46.166.186.228 1080]
E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/k/kali-menu/kali-menu_2017.2.2_all.deb  Connection failed [IP: 46.166.186.228 1080]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

My sources.list

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
```

Comment: Check your network configuration (ip/route/mtu) What is the result of `apt-get update` ?

Comment: @xav-stargate `Ign:1 https://mega.nz/linux/MEGAsync/Debian_9.0 ./ InRelease
Ign:2 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease                
Err:3 https://mega.nz/linux/MEGAsync/Debian_9.0 ./ Release            
  Could not handshake: The TLS connection was non-properly terminated. [IP: 46.166.186.197 1080]
Err:4 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling Release`